# Swift 4 WebKit webView does not load URL with added parameter

Tags: swift, webview, webkit

Just can't find out what is wrong with this `webView`, it just remains blank no error. If I try without a video id parameter and just "https://www.apple.com" it works. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class VideoPlayerVC: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview2: WKWebView!
    var videoId: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      //test video id, this prints the booty workouts id on youtube!This target also opens on youtube the id on the end of this url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=695PN9xaEhs
        if let videoId = videoId {
            print(videoId)
        }

        webview2.load(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(videoId)")))
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your video ID

Comment: I think, you are not getting video ID

Comment: yes, I print it and it gives the right value. Check comment in code the video id is: 695PN9xaEhs

Comment: @PatrikRikama-Hinnenberg you have to ! it as it will be appended as Optional("695PN9xaEhs") in the video url , create the string url then print it before passing it to the URL

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes now I see it prints the optional! Hmm. how to save the unwrapped value before using it again?

Comment: Why are you using `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` when you are clearly inputting a network URL to that initializer? Simply use `URL(string:)` instead.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks good question:) started from beginning and now I got it.

Comment: // testunwrapp videoID and testprint url
        if let videoId = videoId {print(videoId)}
        let targetURL = "\(baseURL)\(videoId!)"
        print(targetURL)
        
        //load webView
        let url = URL(string: "\(targetURL)")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webview2.load(request)

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks, don't know how to upvote you guys but my app works now :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your id is working fine:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=695PN9xaEhs")
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes it works but not with an added parameter. It looks like we are near but still far=) You guys are right its still is the video id that seems to be an optional. How can I save the unwrapped id to anew variable and use it in the appended request @Sh_Khan

Comment: I have a tableview in the previous controller and the videoId provided from that controller. The user chooses the video and thats why the id is needed and created in this VideoPlayerViewController and appended tot the base url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\

Comment: YES! @JogendarChoudhary This works also with the parameter! Thank you !

Comment: Voted for this but looks like my poor reputation does not affect voting answers!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to load an HTTP site instead of HTTPS.
Initially it didn't load anything but when I used HTTPS, the site loaded as expected.